# Synchronize testing thread, UI thread, and CursorLoader thread

Tags: android, multithreading, testing, android-listview, synchronization

My understanding is that Android instrumented JUnit tests run on their own thread unless annotated with `@UiThread` or calling [`Instrumentation.runOnMainSync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#runOnMainSync(java.lang.Runnable)) or [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). Now I'm trying to use a `CursorLoader` to access my app's database and populate a `ListView`. I also have a test which verifies that the `ListView` is populated correctly.

My problem is that I need to synchronize three threads: the test thread should wait until the `CursorLoader` thread finishes and notifies the UI thread to populate the `ListView`. To create a `CursorLoader`, I register a `LoaderCallbacks` with the support `LoaderManager` and create the instance in `onCreateLoader()`. Then `onLoadFinished()` changes the cursor of the `ListView`'s adapter.

Now I need to ensure that my test waits until `onLoadFinish()` has been called before attempting to access the child views of the `ListView`. My current idea is to add a `waitForData()` method to my `LoaderCallbacks` implementation which the tests can call. However, I'm not sure how to implement this method. Can I simply use a `wait()` and then `notifyAll()` in `onLoadFinished()`? Or do I need to use something more sophisticated like a `Semaphore`?

Answer (score 0):

[Espresso](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#Espresso) handles this type of synchronization. I have not yet worked with it to figure out the details, but it looks very promising.